# Any Rails gem for express1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, usps

I need to print USPS shipping label.
My client wants to use express1(http://www.express1.com/usps-parcel-service.html).
I can't find any gem for it.

Anyone experienced it?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1):

I've never come across any Express1 gems. If you're interested: I'm the technical lead at Shippo (https://goshippo.com). Our USPS rates are better than Express1 and we have up-to-date client libraries, e.g. https://github.com/goshippo/shippo-ruby-client.

Let me know if I can help further!

Simon